# In IOS core audio, how do you find the true current play head position of a file player audio unit?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I have a program that uses a file player audio unit to play, pause and stop a audio file. The way I am accomplishing this is by initializing the file player audio unit to play the file at position zero and then when the user presses the pause button, I stop the AUGraph, capture the current position, and then use that position as the start position when the user presses the play button. Everything is working as it should, but every 3 or 4 times I hit pause and then play, the song starts playing a half to a full second BEFORE the point where I hit pause.

I can't figure out why this is happening, do any of you have any thoughts? here is a simplified version of my code.

```
//initialize AUGraph and File player Audio unit
...
...
...

//Start AUGraph 
...
...
...

// pause playback
- (void) pauseAUGraph {

//first stop the AuGrpah
        result = AUGraphStop (processingGraph);

// get current play head position        
        AudioTimeStamp ts;
        UInt32 size = sizeof(ts);

        result = AudioUnitGetProperty(filePlayerUnit, 
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_CurrentPlayTime, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &ts, 
                                      &size);
        //save our play head position for use later
        //must add it to itself to take care of multiple presses of the pause button
        sampleFrameSavedPosition = sampleFrameSavedPosition + ts.mSampleTime; 


        //this stops the file player unit from playing
        AudioUnitReset(filePlayerUnit, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0); 
        NSLog (@"AudioUnitReset - stopped file player from playing");

    //all done    
}


// Stop playback

- (void) stopAUGraph {
        // lets set the play head to zero, so that when we restart, we restart at the beginning of the file. 

          sampleFrameSavedPosition = 0;
        //ok now that we saved the current pleayhead position, lets stop the AUGraph
        result = AUGraphStop (processingGraph);
}
```

Comment: What format is the audio file?

Comment: OK, I'm not an expert in audio compression, but files tend to be compressed in chunks and when you seek it may be going to the nearest chunk rather than the actual position.  If I come across anything more definitive I'll post an answer.

Comment: did anyone solve this? i'm experiencing the same issue. i am using a displaylink at 60 fps to play a metronome synced to the currentTime of audio played with an audio unit. i notice a 0.05s lag which is  quite noticeable

Comment: Hi @Beleg Could you please tell me how to get the time in seconds during the playing song? i.e 0,1,2 .... seconds . I want to show time in seconds in the player

Answer (score 2):

May be you should use packet counts instead of timestamps, since you just want to pause and play the music, not display the time information.

See [BufferedAudioPlayer](https://github.com/iitotoro/BufferedAudioPlayer) for an example of using this method.

Comment: So you are suggesting using a rendercallback instead of a file Player audio unit and counting packets instead of using timestamps? I will give that a try tonight.

Comment: Yes. I used this successfully in more than one project. Audiograph (https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph) is another example that takes the same approach. That project comes with a very good manual, too.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to rounding problems with your code:

For example, if every time you hit the pause button, your timer would record at a 0.5/4 seconds before your actual pause time, you would still see a desired result. But after repeating for four more times, the amount of space you have created is 0.5/4 times 4 which is the half of a second you seem to be experiencing.

Thus, I would pay careful attention to the object types you are using and make sure they don't round inappropriately. Try using a `double float` for your sample times to try to alleviate that problem!

Hope this is clear and helpful! :)

Comment: I am using a float64 to store the audioTimeStamp.mSampletime into sampleFrameSavedPosition so there should not be any rounding errors.    I did notice that when I start the AuGraph back up by setting ScheduledAudioFileRegion.mStartFrame   that ScheduledAudioFileRegion.mStartFrame is a UInt32 and not a float64, that being said when I test my program and print the values of mSampleTime is always an integer so it should not mater.

Comment: Then in theory, if all your types are integers, it should not even output a fraction. Did you try to output the head position every time and see if it added up?